# Why my android room viewmodel returns null object?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I want to design the database in my application using room. I have created all necesary classes. My add query is working fine. But when I use a select query and try to fetch some data from the database, it returns null object. I don't find the problem in it. My entity is User class. I have created User dao, User repository, and User viewmodel. In my fragment I want to fetch data from the database. Part of my fragment is:

```
private boolean invalidPass(String user, String pass) {
        boolean invalid = false;
        LiveData<User> userLog = nUserViewModel.getUserByPhone(user);
        if (!userLog.getValue().getPass().equals(pass))
            invalid = true;
        return invalid;
 }
```

My dao is here:

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {

    @Insert
    public void addUser(User user); //this works fine

    @Query("SELECT * from user_info") //does not work
    List<User> getAllUsers();

    @Query("SELECT * from user_info where phone= :phoneN") //does not work
    public LiveData<User> getUserByPhone(String phoneN);

    @Query("UPDATE user_info SET pass = :passN where phone= :phoneN")
    public void updatePassword(String passN, String phoneN);

    @Delete
    public void deleteUser(User user);
}
```

Repository:

```
public LiveData<User> getUserByPhone(String phone) {
       userNow = mUserDao.getUserByPhone(phone);
       return userNow;
    }
```

view model:

```
public LiveData<User> getUserByPhone(String phone) {
        return mRepository.getUserByPhone(phone);
    }
```

Error shows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String <package name>.User.getPass()' on a null object reference
```

The user object is:

```
public User(@NonNull String phone, String name, String dob, String address, String email, String pass) {
        this.phone=phone;
        this.name = name;
        this.dob=dob;
        this.address=address;
        this.email=email;
        this.pass=pass;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(@NonNull String uPhone) {
        this.phone = uPhone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String uName) {
        this.name = uName;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String uDOB) {
        this.dob = uDOB;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String uAddress) {
        this.address = uAddress;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String uEmail) {
        this.email = uEmail;
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPass(String uPass) {
        this.pass = uPass;
    }
```

Comment: could you please post the User and Pass object source code... as the exception, maybe the save is not working...

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR I have added the user object. Pass is a string

Comment: are you sure that your user class is well annotated? Do you see any saved user on the databases? how your are testing that the @Insert is working?

Comment: @AnisBENNSIR Insert is working. I checked it by inserting a user value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Observe the LiveData with a Observer and in the Observer you are getting the User Object. It is async so your method would not work because you don't have direct access to the User object and that is why you are getting a NullPointerException. Simply because the User Object isn't directly available.
If you are in a Fragment you call addObserver() on the LiveData passing getViewLifecycleOwner() and a Observer.

Comment: Still, it is not working. The same null object error comes. Actually, I don't need to use livedata here. How do I read data from the database without using livedata? I don't want to read it in the main thread though. For writing, I am using databaseWriteExecutor. But how to read?

Comment: If you don't need LiveData User Object then you should return an User Object in your DAO Class instead of a LiveData Object. Then you have direct access to it but as you said, you shouldn't do it on the MainThread because it will throw an exception. And you should always check if the User object is null before you access it because maybe it simply doesn't exist in your table!

Comment: And if the method to return all users returns a List with 0 size, something seems to go wrong with your addUser method. So how do you actually know that your insert method is working? How do you confirm that if you are unable to get users from your table?

Comment: I checked my table in the sql browser. It shows the user in the table. I try to login with that user. So, it should get the data

Comment: That is really strange. Please post your full User class with Room annotations, maybe something is wrong with your implementation.

Comment: Are you sure the phone number is added properly to the Database? Because in your constructor you have annotated it with NonNull, so maybe it is null in your Database and so your query returns no results. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Sorry, most probably somehow my db got deleted. Thanks

Comment: if the insert is working, the call to  List<User> getAllUsers() must return users. is it your case?